# Transistor Video Amp Circuit Help

Tags: circuit-analysis, circuit-design, power-electronics, video-transmitter

I built the below video amp & it worked nicely.But it is One in One out video amp.
http://www.learningelectronics.net/circuits/video-amplifier.html

Now I want One in TWO out Video distributor.I added the red colored capacitor coupled but did not worked.Without the capacitors it is working nicely.

Any Ideas?[image]

Comment: Even if the target device should *(or may)* have coupling cap at its input, you may need to use a coupling cap at the output of your amplifier circuit since it has DC offset. I think you can put only one coupling cap right at the output (i.e. collector) then use 75R split resistors.

Comment: Hi I did as you suggested, Added a single 100uF to the COllector output & split into two via two 75R resistors but that didn't work either.Also lowered the capacitor down to 10uF but nothing helped :(.

Comment: The reason I like to put the capacitors is because, by mistake if the output short circuit, the transistor will blow up :(

Comment: What, exactly, does "not worked" mean? Amplitude low? Amplitude zero? Something else?

Comment: Not worked means, Video is not coming.It shows Video loss in the monitor.But when I short the capacitor it is working fine.

Comment: 100uF (regardless of other problems) is probably not the best choice.  Larger parts have higher inductance, and might be attenuating your signal.  Look at the coupling capacitor on the input.  It is only 1uF - and could probably be smaller.

Answer (score 2):

This is a very interesting circuit. I've used similar, for very fast (10nanosecond pulses) amplification with 2N3904/3906, where I needed better dynamic response than opamps could provide and still work within 0/5volt rails (this was many years ago). This circuit is actually 1/2 of a current mode opamp, and the emitter of the NPN is the summing node.

The input circuit, especially with that diode, looks like a sync-tip clamping circuit, a peak-detector, that controls the biasing of the entire amplifier. Thus the black and the white levels depend on how you set P1.

The feedback circuit is P2, and setting the pot wiper in the middle should provide a gain of TWO. This gain of TWO is needed to overcome the 2:1 voltage division of the 75ohm Rout and the termination resistor, also 75 ohms, at end of the video coax cable.

Now ---- why do your modifications not work?

Knowing this circuit rather well, my first thought is "That 5Kohm pot P2 is the **ONLY** DC pulldown. That will not work."

The 75 ohms is also the DC_pulldown (actually 75 + 75 = 150 ohms).

I suggest you **remove** the output capacitors.

The extra 14 milliamp may overload your +5 power supply. Probably not. But check that.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the detailed explanation.If I remove the output capacitors will it burn the transistor if I short circuit the output to Ground by mistake?

Comment: You still have the local 75 ohm resistors to limit the current. But do not short the collector to ground.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the details.I tested this circuit on a Vero Board using CAT5E Twisted cables on workbench. Regarding the video quality, I like if it has a little bit of sharpness on video.Do not not know the lack of sharpness is due to the poor board quality or cable issues...!!! Is there anyway to improve little bit of sharpness...!!

Comment: With the amplifier connected  in the video path as you look at the video monitor, use scope probes in 10x mode, and look for ringing or slow settling (needs 0.1uf on emitter of the pnp) or slow rise or fall time. Maybe reduce r1 and r4; for low inductance tie coax gnds  to bottom of c3 and c4.

Comment: Hi, you mean to add another 0.1uF capacitor in parallel with 1uF (C3)?

Comment: I've used VERO   boards, successfully, for circuits such as this, but for SLOW NTSC B&W video gain=4x into a 8-bit-flash ADC. I want you to be successful, and short GND wiring and low-inductance bypass capacitors are needed for very fast pixel rise/fall times. I don't know how the 1uF  cap is wired. If you can, show a picture of your VERO board, with GND and VDD traces clearly indicated.